# HTTP AUTH authentification NOT WORKING on ANDROID

Tags: android

I am working with an IP camera, i need to get the picture from my android application, 
First i have made an application in JAVA "standard", i use the same code for receive the stream in my android app.

The problem : "Authenticator" is simply not working on android, Yes i know on android it's not a standard VM, but it's in the google code so ..

I use it for the "login"

```
 Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator(){
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication("user","pass".toCharArray());
    }});
```

I find an other topic (I have search a lot about it ..) where people say "the google code have a problem" they was speaking about a fix, but the topic was made around 2006 - 2010 ... We are in 2014

I can only use it for connect my HttpURLConnection, i can't use the tweak with headers because it only works with "BASIC" authentification, me in my case i need it to work with "AUTH" authentification ...

PS : The most topic we found they speak for a "BASIC" authentification, who is more "easy" to do (just in the http header), but in my case I NEED TO USE the "AUTH" type

EDIT: I have the link about "some topics" who relate the problem :

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9579

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4326

(if it can help), but again, people who work with BASIC authentification, can tweak the headers for "conturning" the problem, but me i can't because it's "AUTH" type

Thanks for help,